# ECI to LVLH transformation

Tags: orbit, spacecraft, propulsion, attitude

I am working on a transformation of ECI coordinates to LVLH (Local Vertical Local Horizontal) coordinates in order to calculate satellite maneuvers. Does anybody know how should I approach the problem? Are there examples available?

*the model is not a chaser-target model*

Comment: I don't have a chaser-target problem here..

Comment: The first three equations are what you need. You can ignore the rest.

Comment: thank you @OrganicMarble! Any idea on how to calculate yaw, pitch, and roll?

Comment: Y-P-R is no different in an LVLH frame than any other: the angular difference between the body frame and the external coordinate frame. There are hundreds of posts on the internet about how to calculate Y-P-R.